# Find all solutions of the equation $3 \cdot 2^{x+2}+5^x=8\cdot 3^x+5$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

> Find all solutions of the equation
>   $$3 \cdot 2^{x+2}+5^x=8\cdot 3^x+5$$

**My work so far:**

Let $f(x)=3 \cdot 2^{x+2}+5^x-8\cdot 3^x-5$

$f'(x)=12\cdot 2^x\ln2+5^x\ln5-8\cdot3^x\ln3$

Comment: I guess it is the only solution!!

Comment: Solutions: 0, 1, 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation can be changed to $$5(5^{x-1}-1)=24(3^{x-1}-2^{x-1})$$
At least $x=0$, $x=1$ and $x=3$ are solutions.

If your question is a Diophantine problem:

With $n_1,n_2\in\mathbb{N}$ you have the conditions $$3^{x-1}-2^{x-1}=5n_1$$ $$5^{x-1}-1=24n_2$$

EDIT: 
$x\in\mathbb{R}$ o.k.

But with the values 0,1,3 you can check 
$$5(5^{x-1}-1)<,=,>24(3^{x-1}-2^{x-1})$$ 
with $x<0$, $0<x<1$, $1<x<3$ and $x>3$

Comment: $x \in \mathbb R \not\Rightarrow n_1,n_2 \in \mathbb N$